# Problem with livenessProbe and httpHeaders

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am setting a cluster and in one of my pods I have HTTPS redirection, to handle the health/readiness checks. I have created a whitelist for a header. The problem comes when I watch the log of my application to trace the readiness/health probe and I see that there is no evidence of the header check arriving with the HTTP request and therefore the application is redirecting the check, this leads the check to fail and the service to drop.

Do I need to do some extra configuration in the service or is there something missing?

I have already tried the application without HTTPS redirection and it works. Also checked the whitelist in local and also works.

Extract from my YAML definition

```
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.web.name }}-web
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
            httpHeaders:
            - name: Health-check
              value: "true"
        readiessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 80
            httpHeaders:
            - name: Health-check
              value: "true"
```

Comment: Can you [capture some of the readiness probes to make sure the header is included](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/how-to-monitor-incoming-http-requests) and formatted in the way your application is expecting to see it?